# Efficiently convert a SAS dataset into a CSV

Tags: csv, sas

Can anyone tell me what is the fastest way to programmatically convert a SAS dataset into a CSV file. I know I can use a data step and output to a file etc. But is that the only way?

Thanks,
Adnan.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

something along these lines?

```
proc export data=sashelp.class
    outfile='c:\temp\sashelp class.csv'
    dbms=csv
    replace;
run;
```

Comment: Yes that was one of the options we'd discussed. Do you know how it scales vs the data step approach?

Comment: based on the log, proc export generates a data null step to write out the text file. so i'd guess using a data step from the start would be more efficient in terms of cpu time. data step would give you more control over the output.

Comment: I'm probably going to end up using a data _null_ anyway because I'd like to have control over which columns get exported, and things iike formatting/not formatting column values etc.

Comment: FYI I've noticed that I have to use the -noterminal option when running a SAS program (in batch mode) that uses proc export to create a csv or other flat file.

Answer (score 11):

5 different ways to create .CSV file of a SAS dataset.

refer http://studysas.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-create-comma-separated-file-csv.html

Comment: You missed the `%ds2csv` macro: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lebaseutilref/64791/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0yo3bszlrh0byn1j4fxh4ndei8u.htm

Answer (score 8):

The answers here have addressed many ways to create a csv, but not necessarily the efficiency of these methods. I create a sample dataset (`temp`) with 100,000 rows and five columns to test and compare the methods for export the sas dataset to a csv named `temp.csv`.

---

The first method: The **Export Procedure**. Run time: **0.43** seconds.

```
PROC EXPORT data=temp 
     outfile="temp.csv" dbms=csv replace;
```

Quick run time and simple, in-the-box flexibility when choosing other options. With that said, it is not the strongest for customization

---

The second method: **ODS with Print Procedure**. Run time: **14.09** seconds.

```
ODS csv file="temp.csv";
PROC PRINT data=temp noobs;
RUN;
ods csv close;
```

This method is the worst option out of the three for most use cases, although there a few special use cases. It is nice for temporary output of previously written procedures, especially if you want the output to stay in the lst file (if it is not too big). It also may be useful when you want to convert another procedure (for instance, a complicated `tabulate`) to file without further manipulation. If you do not need the print out in the lst file, close your listing (`ods listing close`) or this will take much, much longer.

---

The third method: **File Statement**. Run time: **0.06** seconds.

```
DATA _null_;
    FILE "temp.csv ";
    SET temp;
    put (_all_) (',');
RUN;
```

While the performance of this method is not bad, it is not intuitive and looks confusing. As mentioned above however, you would have more control over the output, and it has the quickest run time of them all.

Comment: Caution: The data _null_ method will not output the variable names in the first row of your .csv, which might be a problem.

Comment: You should use the DSD option on the FILE statement instead of writing the delimiter by hand. Otherwise you might not get a file that can be deciphered. Note that it is not very hard to add a little code to write the header row.

Comment: @Tom I feel like there's another answer on its way...?

Answer (score 3):

#### Modified `data _NULL_` approach

Here's a modification to the `data _NULL_` approach that writes out header rows to the file in the first datastep and then continues to write the same file with the data rows in the second datastep.

```
%macro outputCSV(dataset,file);
data _NULL_;
   file "&file." dlm=',' dsd;
   length header $ 2000;
   dsid=open("&dataset.","i");
   num=attrn(dsid,"nvars");
   do i=1 to num;
      header = trim(left(coalescec(varlabel(dsid,i),varname(dsid,i))));
      put header @;
   end;
   rc=close(dsid);
run;

data _NULL_;
   set &dataset.;
   file "&file." mod dlm=',' dsd;
   put (_all_) (+0);
run;
%mend;

%outputCSV(sashelp.class,~/temp4.csv)
```

It can be made to work with `keep` and `drop` data set options (surprisingly), although unfortunately when a dataset is 'opened' using `open()`, the `nvars` attribute respects the new number of variables after `keep` or `drop`, but the `varlabel` and `varname` functions still look for variables using their `varnum`.

In the following example, just `Name` (varnum=1) and `Height` (varnum=4) are extracted from `SASHELP.CLASS`, because only two variables are kept, `nvars` is 2, but if we iterate over a loop with num as the upper bound, we miss out `Height`, because its `varnum` is 4:

```
 62         data _NULL_;
 63           dsid = open("sashelp.class (keep=name height)","i");
 64           num = attrn(dsid,"nvars");
 65           do i=1 to 5;
 66             vname = varname(dsid,i);
 67             put i= vname= num=;
 68           end;
 69         run;
 
 i=1 vname=Name num=2
 NOTE: Argument 2 to function VARNAME(1,2) at line 66 column 13 is invalid.
 i=2 vname=  num=2
 NOTE: Argument 2 to function VARNAME(1,3) at line 66 column 13 is invalid.
 i=3 vname=  num=2
 i=4 vname=Height num=2
 NOTE: Argument 2 to function VARNAME(1,5) at line 66 column 13 is invalid.
 i=5 vname=  num=2
 dsid=1 num=2 i=6 vname=  _ERROR_=1 _N_=1
```

There are two options:

- Extract the true `nvars` value by stripping off the dataset options for the first pass
- Use a really high number instead of `num`, although this just leads to lots of `'invalid'` notes in the log

This is the first approach, requiring two calls to the `open` function:

```
%macro outputCSV(dataset,file);
data _NULL_;
   file "&file." dlm=',' dsd;
   length header $ 2000;
   dsid=open("%SCAN(&dataset.,1,()","i");
   num=attrn(dsid,"nvars");
   rc=close(dsid);
   dsid=open("&dataset.","i");
   do i=1 to num;
      header = trim(left(coalescec(varlabel(dsid,i),varname(dsid,i))));
      if _error_ = 0 then put header @;
      _error_ = 0;
   end;
   rc=close(dsid);
run;

data _NULL_;
   set &dataset.;
   file "&file." mod dlm=',' dsd;
   put (_all_) (+0);
run;
%mend;

%outputCSV(sashelp.class (keep=name height),~/temp4.csv)
```

After writing all of that out, it probably makes sense to go with `PROC EXPORT` in most cases, or explicitly list the variables if there aren't many. This just shows what can be done.

Comment: No need to use those old SCL functions. Just use PROC TRANSPOSE to create a dataset with the variable names in order. `proc transpose data=have(obs=0) out=name; var _all_; run;`  Then use a simple data step to write the header row.  Then add the MOD option to the file statement in the data step that writes the actual data lines.

Comment: Yes, good call, had attempted similar using `array _character_` and its counterpart, but couldn't get the columns to come out in order.

Comment: Thanks @mjsqu!  This is a great answer - I incorporated your code into our macro library, I hope that's ok:  https://core.sasjs.io/mp__ds2csv_8sas.html