# In free SAS University Edition convert .sas7bdat to .csv

Tags: sas, sas-studio

I am using the free SAS university edition in the browser and would like to convert a data set into a csv format. How do I do this?

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711250/efficiently-convert-a-sas-dataset-into-a-csv) but it doesn't work since the browser version doesn't use a traditional file path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PROC EXPORT` or any of the other solutions will work fine. However, you need to be able to identify the location of the shared folder you are using between SAS Studio/University Edition and your main computer.

Assuming you followed the [instructions](https://support.sas.com/software/products/university-edition/faq/shared_folder_whatis.htm) when you set up the SAS University Edition virtual machine, you have a folder located at the virtual path

```
/folders/myfolders/
```

(Or named differently if you named it something else.)  That can then be used as the path to `proc export`.