# anybody has a sample code to import a SAS table into postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sas

I am looking to import a SAS table sas7dat format into postgresql. Or do i need to convert the table into csv then import?
Thank you!

Comment: If you have the product "SAS/ACCESS Interface to PostgreSQL"  licensed you can use `Proc COPY`. I am unaware of a PostgreSQL routine that can read SAS data sets natively.

Comment: thks!! i guess i have to do the long way. :P

Answer (score 3):

If you have already SAS and Postgres at your organization then you probably you might have SAS/Access interface to Postgres. you can use proc setinit;run; to check whether you have SAS/Access interface to Postgres. If you have the SAS/ACCESS then you can use libname method as shown in below example.

/* define libname for postgres*/

```
libname A1 postgres server=mysrv1 port=5432 user=myusr1 password='mypwd1' database=mydb1;
```

/* define libname for SAS table*/

```
 libname mydata '/folders/myfolders/';
```

/* then use datastep or SQL to create your postgress table*/

```
 data A1.yourtable;
  set mydata.yourtable;
  run;
```

If you do not have SAS/ACCESS to postgres then you may have to do in 2 steps.(but check whether you have any etl tools available in your company)

first you have to use proc export to CSV. see the link below

[Efficiently convert a SAS dataset into a CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711250/efficiently-convert-a-sas-dataset-into-a-csv)
                                                                                                 then move csv data into postgres
                                                                                      [How to import CSV file data into a PostgreSQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table)

Comment: Thank you so much! but sadly my company or my sas server does not have sas/access interface to postgres.

Comment: do you have any etl tool with your company

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution which requires Python to import sas7bdat file into Postgres.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/databasename", echo=False)
df = pd.read_sas('sas7bdat file location')
df.to_sql('tablename', con=engine, if_exists='replace')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to import the SAS file into R, then from R write the data to a SQL database using dbWrite.

Personally, I have found that getting data that is in R into a SQL database is easier than trying to get data from a text file into a SQL database.

See https://www.statology.org/import-sas-into-r/

https://dbi.r-dbi.org/reference/dbwritetable

Comment: You can use my wrds2pg package for this. I don't have SAS, so I haven't used that functionality in a while (instead I connect to WRDS, which runs SAS for me). This will be much, much faster than using R for large tables.

https://pypi.org/project/wrds2pg/

Answer (score 0):

You can use my `wrds2pg` package for this: see pypi.org/project/wrds2pg

I don't have SAS, so I haven't used that functionality in a while (instead I connect to WRDS, which runs SAS for me).

Using `wrds2pg` will be much, much faster than using R for large tables. From the `wrds2pg` README:

> The software can also upload SAS file directly to PostgreSQL. You need to have local SAS in order to use this function. Use fpath to specify the path to the file to be imported