# Saving the query results to csv

Tags: sas

I'm wondering if it's possible to save the query results to csv? Without creating views.

I have a large table but need only 2 columns from there to process with python then. Maybe someone can help with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently convert a SAS dataset into a CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711250/efficiently-convert-a-sas-dataset-into-a-csv)

Comment: no, I dont need to export the whole table only a few columns

Comment: You can use any of the options in that answer and add a keep clause to restrict the columns. Where you specify the dataset to be exported via `data=mydata` or `set mydata` you can replace `mydata` with `mydata(keep = col1 col2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three ways

**ODS**

SQL query can be output to an `ODS CSV` destination.  This approach encompasses the widest possibilities of querying.

```
ods csv file='c:\temp\query-results.csv';

proc sql;
  select name, age 
  from sashelp.class
  where name like 'J%'
  ;
quit;

ods csv close;
```

**EXPORT Procedure**

Where clause can be applied **using kept columns** of 'a large table' (`data=`)

```
proc export 
  data = sashelp.class(
    keep=name age
    where = (
      name like 'J%'
    )
  ) 
  replace 
  file = 'c:\temp\class-subset.csv'
  dbms = csv
  ;
run;
```

**DATA _null_**

Where statement can be applied using **any** columns of 'a large table' (`SET`).  The `PUT` statement manages which columns are output.

```
data _null_;
  set sashelp.class;
  where name like 'J%';

  file 'c:\temp\subset-per-datastep.csv' dlm=',' dsd;

  if _n_ = 1 then put 'name,age';
  put name age;
run;
```

Comment: Nice, the only other method I can think of is the `%ds2csv()` utility macro, but I'm sure there's probably other ways too... I wonder how many we're missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ods to create file with results, for example:

```
ods csv file="C:\test.csv" options(delimiter=';');

proc sql;
   select * from sashelp.class;
quit;

ods csv close;
```